# Extracting urls from html: fix truncated

Tags: url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

When scraping through a website, urls are being parsed:

```
for url in soup.find_all('a', class_='result-title hdrlnk'):
print(url)
```

But extracted links certainly have truncated format and when tested they go in two formats: either complete url, but no "http:" or "http://" and domain name is missing.

How to:

1. Analyze the type of url truncation?
2. How to append initial part of a url depending on result of that analysis?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `urljoin` . In python 2 it's part of the `urlparse` lib, in python 3 it's in `urllib.parse` .
This example works for both versions :

```
try : 
    from urllib.parse import urljoin    # python 3.x #
except ImportError : 
    from urlparse import urljoin    # python 2.x # 

base_url = 'http://' + 'www.domain.com'    # scheme + netloc #  
urls = [ url for url in soup.find_all('a', class_='result-title hdrlnk') ]
full_urls = [ urljoin(base_url, url.get('href')) for url in urls ]

urls_text = [ [ urljoin(base_url, url.get('href')), url.text ] for url in urls ]
f = open("output1.html", "w") 
f.write('\r\n'.join('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(*url) for url in urls_text))
f.close()
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you, thank you so much! One thing: do you think you know how I may also extract text in a href tags? So it would be printed in links+text and when saved to HTML would appear as hyperlinks with text?

Comment: What is netloc?

Comment: Netloc stands for network location ( the domain ) . If you want href and text i think you should use a nested list. I updated my post, check the last lines.

Comment: How do I save it to a file? with open("output1.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(full_urls))
    file.close()?  what if I need hyperlink text in my html file, not plain text? thanks

Comment: Don't use `str` to turn list to string, you 'll end up with a bunch of brackets. I updated the code, give it a try.

Comment: for url in urls_text : 
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: file.write('<a href="{}">{}</a>\n'.format(*url))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: f.write('\r\n'.join('<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(*url) for url in urls_text))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

Comment: [reading-and-writing-unicode-data](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)

Comment: so i need to add encoding= parameter into the line?

Comment: If you're using python 3 yes. Just follow the docs and you should be ok

Comment: but why does that ask for enconoding in the firstplace, previous code wouldn't ask specific coding instruction

Comment: There is a difference between printing to terminal or ide and writting to file.

Comment: Thank you, pal, I included attributes for the bloody encoding. You're really navigating me through this. I got the whole list. But the list goes without any breaklines/paragraphing. Can it be arranged to paragraphed list?

Comment: Easy, just add a <br> at the end of each <a>  ie : `'<a href="{}">{}</a><br>'`

Comment: cheers, Adam, it worked out. if you feel like giving me another hint, I'd rather ask how I make Python navigate through several webpages, not only one? How to make iterations? Let's say I know the pattern(mask) of a url that indicates the next page, which is ?s=0 and inc is 120; I am using url = then request =  requests.get(url)
mysoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text) then mysoup.select, but I do not know what algorithm to put into mysoup.select, to make Python iterate ?s=0(+120). and I don't know how to loop parsing once every other page is opened and continue until it's the last page

Comment: Are you trying to write a crawler? I think this should be a new question, i'm sure you 'll get lots of help on this site :)

Comment: Thank you. Trying to write a  a parser but more trying to get the feel of python

Answer (score 0):

t.m.adam has a great response to this question **however**, I used something like this.

```
base = 'http://example.com/'
for url in soup.find_all('a', class_='result-title hdrlnk'):
    if url.startswith('http:'):
        pass
    else:
        new_var = 'http://'+url
        #or new_var = base+url
```

The urljoin is a better method so I propose that. This is a very error-prone method, example: if the url is ftp://someting.de it will add http://ftp://something.de and so on.

Comment: Thank you, Elvir, frankly, I did not use your method, cause I am a complete rookie in Python, and I just tread very carefully, Adam's method worked for me. And I am like: it works - don't touch it. I can't afford being very free and easy yet)

Comment: Awesome, that's why I suggested his method. It's far better but for the purpose of understanding I've added an answer. Method .startswith is used to check whether a string starts with some other string.